# Flask Catch-All Error - unexpected keyword argument 'path'

Tags: python, flask

I was trying to create a catch-all route with flask, using this snippet:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1/<path:path>')
def api():
    return 'You want path: %s' % path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But got this error when running it in my app:

> got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot to add path as a parameter in my function:

def api(**path**)

```
@app.route('/api/v1/<path:path>')
def api(path): <---
    return 'You want path: %s' % path
```